# Generic.Collection.Dictionary(K, V)

Tags: delphi, pascal

Где для TDictionary описаны параметры ключа (К) и значения (V) ?

Comment: Что значит "описаны параметры"? TKey и TValue - типы для инстанцирования дженерика

Comment: наверное ДА, я скорее всего не правильно написал!
есть вот такой код:  TDictionary<K,V> = class(TEnumerable<TPair<K,V>>)
  private type
    TItem = record
      HashCode: Integer;
      Key: K;
      Value: V;
    end;
откуда берутся K и V

Comment: Из конструктора в вашем коде. Например, когда вы пишите `TDictionary<string, Integer>.Create;` то K и V это string и integer соответственно.

Comment: с этим то же знаком, меня интересует как можно отдельно использовать K и V как тип данных которые я описываю в var

Comment: K и V - это параметры..отдельно вы их никак не можете использовать. Вы можете наследовать/имплементировать классы/интерфейсы, использующие параметризированные типы и там можете играться с ними. Можете создать свой класс с параметризированным типом и играться внутри него.

Comment: если я всё правильно понял, то это как мне указал MBo ниже

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, вы впервые сталкиваетесь с дженериками. При написании реального кода вместо обобщённых параметров при объявлении и при создании подставляете нужные вам в данном месте **типы**, и затем используете  подобным образом:

```
Dct:  TDictionary<Integer, String>;

Dct := TDictionary<Integer, String>.Create;
Dct.Add(1, 'Один');
```

Comment: да, я это знаю. меня интересует какой из модулей надо подключить что бы я у себя в программе мог использовать эти типы данных, т.е. написал KeyVar: K; ValueVar: V

Comment: Скорее всего, срабатывает разница в обучении паскалю (как правило, в чисто процедурном плане) и delphi: я часто сталкивался с подобным, когда работал со студентами

Comment: и как выходили из данного положения? что объясняли ученикам?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, зачем нужно писать KeyVar: K; ValueVar: V ?  Это ведь просто условное обозначение параметров-типов, которые будут использоваться внутри класса дженерика. Если мы пишем свой такой класс, то переменные этих типов внутри будут(могут) использоваться, а в программе вне класса  этих типов просто не существует.

Comment: как они будет использоваться в классе который я хочу написать, если у меня при написании сразу выдаётся ошибка на данном участке кода (не известный идентификатор), подразумевается что данные переменные могут принять любой тип (это в джинерике и там нет ошибки), а у меня в классе при описании такой же структуры возникает ошибка

Comment: Показывайте тогда, чего писали.

Comment: type
  TValues = class
    KeyVar: K;
    ValueVar: V;
  end;
на K и V ругается сразу, в uses System.Types,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.StrUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections; уже не знаю что добавить

Comment: type TValues<K,V>=class

Comment: вот спасибо! я где то пропустил такой вид описания класса

Comment: Ну вы же сами приводили описание TDictionary<K,V>

Comment: да, приводил, но там я не задумался что это параметры самого класса. ещё вопрос (наверное немного не в тему), обязательно параметры должны быть обозначены буквами K,V и Т или можно как обычных процедурах/функциях использовать любые буквы?

Comment: Нет, можно любые буквы. По соглашению единственный параметр обычно T (подчеркивает, что это тип), в словаре K и V для того, чтобы было понятно, что это key value, но в общем использовать можно любые идентификаторы (не только одна буква), какие удобно

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение))))